# How can I add a loop inside a function which could invoke agent.add couple of times in Dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to make a Google action using Dialogflow. But I am stuck with the following condition:
I want to invoke agent.add multiple times in a loop like this -

```
function xyz(agent){
   for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
      agent.add('hello');
   }
}
```

But each time it invokes agent.add twice:
Like -

> Agent : hello
>
> Agent : hello

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Agent.

Answer (score 0):

When using agent.add() in Dialogflow, the messages get converted to Simple Responses in Actions on Google.
Google actions only [allow](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/simple-responses#SimpleResponseProperties) for two text bubbles per turn. 
You can add other elements such as image cards and tables besides the bubbles, but a response cannot contain more than two chat bubbles.

So there is no work around for this, its a limitation from the platform.